# Reading raster cell values on specific PostgreSQL points with rasterio and updating PostgreSQL table with those values?

Tags: python, postgresql, rasterio

I have 9 UK wide raster files (TIFF) and about 3 millions points on a PostgreSQL table. I need to add, for each point on the pg table, the values of the 9 raster cells where the point falls in.

I am trying with the following piece of code:

```
pg_table = '.....'

#Here I create 9 new fields in the pg table to store the 9 values
query = """ALTER TABLE """ + pg_table + """
           ADD COLUMN U_R_20 numeric,
           ADD COLUMN U_R_75 numeric,
           ADD COLUMN U_R_100 numeric,
           ADD COLUMN U_R_200 numeric,
           ADD COLUMN U_R_1000 numeric, 
           ADD COLUMN U_C_75 numeric,
           ADD COLUMN U_C_100 numeric,  
           ADD COLUMN U_C_200 numeric,  
           ADD COLUMN U_C_1000 numeric;"""
cursor.execute(query)
con.commit()

raster1_path = '....tif'
raster2_path = '....tif'
...
raster9_path = '....tif'

river_1 = rasterio.open(raster1_path)
...
river_9 = rasterio.open(raster9_path)

#Create list with all paths of tiff files
rasters = [river_1, ... , river_9]

#Select all midpoints and find out, one by one, value of raster cell where midpoint falls in (for all 9 rasters)
selection = etl.fromdb(con, "SELECT feature_id, ST_AsText(geom) FROM {0}".format(pg_midpts))
for (id, geom) in selection[1:len(selection)]:    #First element is only the attribute name
    #Convert the 'geometry' string of characters into an actual shapely point (type shapely).
    pnt = shapely.wkt.loads(geom)
    #Create list to store cell values where midpoint falls in
    values = []
    #Iterate through all 9 rasters to extract their values on current point
    for i in range(0, len(rasters)):
        #xxx.sample() takes an iterator over x, y tuples, so:
        for val in rasters[i].sample([(pnt.x, pnt.y)]):
            values.append(val[0])    #function sample returns a numpy array with only one element. We extract it with [0]

    #Insert values from rasters into table
    query23 = """UPDATE """ + pg_midpts + """
                 SET U_R_20={0}, U_R_75={1}, U_R_100={2}, U_R_200={3}, U_R_1000={4},
                     U_C_75={5}, U_C_100={6}, U_C_200={7}, U_C_1000={8}
                 WHERE feature_id = {9};""".format(values[0], values[1], values[2],  \
                                                   values[3], values[4], values[5],  \
                                                   values[6], values[7], values[8], id)
    cursor.execute(query23)
    con.commit()
```

This code seems to be working fine. However, it takes about 48 hours.

Is there any way to optimise what I am trying to do? Or maybe a completely different approach?

PS: By the way. ArcMap has a tool to do that (extract multiple values), but it doesn't work at all, it just messes up the whole table.

Answer (score 1):

1. Query point data into a pandas dataframe ([link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.read_sql.html)) like

`df_pnts = pd.read_sql("SELECT feature_id, geom.X as x, geom.Y as y FROM {0}".format(pg_table), con=con)`

2. Extract sample data (don't loop over each point). Pseudocode:

`for r in rasters:
    with rasterio.open(r) as src:
        df[r] = src.sample(xy_pairs)`

3. Push data back to postgres with pandas ([link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)) like

`df[[**LIST OF COLUMNS**]].to_sql('newTableName',con=con)`

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Rowan. Sorry, just saw your answer. So, using pandas should be faster than petl to do SQL queries? Do you know the reason why? 
I don't quite understand the second bit. What would xy_pairs be? And how do you extract a sample of data instead looping over each point? [NOTE: I improved my script quite a lot by taking the 'rasterio.open' out of the loop, which was a pretty silly mistake. Now it takes 48 hours, but I still think it takes too long -arcmap takes less-]

Comment: Hi Pitrako, sorry for not getting back to you sooner. I am not sure if pandas is any faster, just thought it would be easier to use (the data will be in a dataframe) and you can easily push it back to the database. The xy pairs should be the x and y coordinates from your table... something like: [[x1,y1],[x2,y2],[x3,y3],[x4,y4],....]. Not sure if rasterio needs them in a certain format though (e.g. tuple,list, or array). Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Rowan. And it's now (almost 1 month later) that I have had the chance to come back to this and do some testing following your suggestion. I have run your code, but instead of adding a new field with the value of the raster on each point it adds a new field where each element is a <generator object sample_gen at 0x000......>. Not sure what this means.